# Add a header field, and the file's name at the end of the data lines, for all the csv files in a folder

Tags: text-processing, command-line, filenames, csv-simple

I want to add filename (without extension) at the end for all the lines for all the csv files in a folder. All the files are having the same header.

Let's say I have two files a.csv and b.csv in a folder.

a.csv contains (first line is a header)

```
num1,num2,num3  
1,2,3
```

b.csv contains (first line is a header)

```
num1,num2,num3    
4,5,6
```

I want a.csv file to be (first line is a header)

```
num1,num2,num3,filename  
1,2,3,a
```

I want b.csv file to be (first line is a header)

```
num1,num2,num3,filename  
4,5,6,b
```

How can I do it in Unix?

Comment: you want to append the filename to every line in the file? to every line except the first? to only the 2nd?

Comment: Or do you want to change the filename based on the first (or possibly second) line in the file?

Comment: Yes, I want to append the filename to every line in the file.  Ideally in the first line  which is a header I want to append as "filename". For all the other lines I want to append the actual file name.

Answer (score 3):

```
for file in *.csv
do
  filename=${file%.csv}
  sed -i -e "1s/\$/,filename/; 2,\$s/\$/,$filename/" "$file"
done
```

1. Loop through every `*csv` file in the current directory,
2. prepare the filename text by stripping off the trailing `.csv`
3. edit the file with sed, `-i` in-place, by:

   1. on line 1 only, search and replace the end of the line (escaped `$`) with the `,filename` text.
   2. on lines 2 through the end of the file (`$`), search and replace the end of the line (`$`) with a comma and the prepared filename

Answer (score 2):

If I understood the OP correctly, then the "ideal" solution is (line 1 w/o extension, rest with extension), using `GNU awk`:

```
gawk -F, -i inplace \
'BEGIN {
    OFS=",";
 }
 {
    if(FNR==1)
        name = gensub(/^(.*)\..*/, "\\1", "g", FILENAME);
    else
        name = FILENAME;

    print $0, name;
 }' *.csv
```

The `-F`, handle and the `OFS=","` assignment set input and output field-separator to `,`.

`-i inplace` means to truncate current record in the file and write current output instead into the file.

The gensub built-in saves the filename without extension in name and the print statement prints the desired modified record.

Comment: I have thousands of .csv files in the folder. Can we use  for loop so that files can be auto picked ?

Comment: Yes that would help

Comment: Use *.csv instead

Comment: @AFSHIN: I don't think so. He said: "Ideally in the first line which is a header I want to append as "filename". For all the other lines I want to append the actual file name" , which imho is consistent with my interpretation.

Comment: oops, OP's comment is completely different with his question's body, deleted my comment

Answer (score 1):

The following command uses [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`) to read the CSV files, and to each file add a new field called `filename`, containing the pathname of the current file (as given on the command line) with `.csv` removed from the end.

```bash
mlr -I --csv put '$filename = sub(FILENAME,"\.csv$","")' a.csv b.csv
```

With `-I`, the changes are made to the files in-place, and each file is processed in isolation. The rest should be familiar from `awk`, with the added benefit that we can reference fields by name. Assigning to a new field name creates that field.

Miller will automatically quote any field that require quoting.

```bash
$ cat a.csv
num1,num2,num3
1,2,3
```

```bash
$ cat b.csv
num1,num2,num3
4,5,6
```

```bash
$ mlr -I --csv put '$filename = sub(FILENAME,"\.csv$","")' a.csv b.csv
```

```bash
$ cat a.csv
num1,num2,num3,filename
1,2,3,a
```

```bash
$ cat b.csv
num1,num2,num3,filename
4,5,6,b
```